How do I fail a build if the project contains an incorrectly named directory?
I have a developer on the team that sometimes incorrectly names directories. Let say the are creating a new class in a package a.b.c. Under src/main/java they will create a directory literally named a.b.c. I tried to increase the beatings, but they still keep doing this.
To my surprise, both maven and javac are fine with this - the project builds and tests run. Later the maven-javadoc-plugin panics and fails. Unfortunatelly, we do not build the site (with javadocs) for our feature branches, only for the main branch ... after this mistake is merged.
I would prefer to make this situation a build failure. Are there any options to do that?

First do you have a review/PR process that things like that will be recognized earlier... technically speaking a a.b.c is a directory... you might create a custom https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin enforcer rule which checks a package name or you could check for https://www.archunit.org/ which could also check the package structure...

I wonder why these directories are created manually. I always use the IDE to create me a "package" and this automatically creates the correct directory.

@JFabianMeier Agreed. I personally have never had this happen to me. I cannot figure out what the (one) developer is doing wrong. :-\

@khmarbaise We do have a PR process, but I feel like something like this should be done by a machine.

You can write a maven-enforcer-rule for that, and that will certainly work, but I guess it would also be good to train those developers more in the usage of their IDE. Maybe they need to pair with a colleague for a while, or do an online course.

Yes pairing is also a very good way... as @JFabianMeier suggested...

Did you tried this:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/main/package/*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/my/package/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


This sounds like I would need to know all the possible invalid package names up front?

No
Can exclude * with regex ans include (just) project package (also with regex).
